# Not sure why this is entering the final if statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So I am doing a HackerRank JavaScript Challenge(Array Section), basically I need to find the second largest number in an array. I was getting close and looked in the discussion to help get my answer but I'm confused on how it works.
The nums array is an array of numbers of n length, which allows duplicates.
n can be 1<=n<10, nums can be 1<=nums<=100.
 The code I have is here :

```
function getSecondLargest(nums)
{
    var largestNum = nums[0];
    var secondLargest = nums[0]; 

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i] > largestNum)
        {

            secondLargest = largestNum;
            largestNum = nums[i];

                continue;
        }

        if ((nums[i] > secondLargest) && (nums[i] < largestNum))
        {
            secondLargest = nums[i];
        }
    }

    return secondLargest;
```

So I know by the final loop iteration that secondLargest = 9.

My issue is I believe LargestNum = 10 by the end of the final loop, first if block. So if LargestNum = 10, How does that fulfill this if statement requirement.

num[9] = 10   (I think)

largestNum = 10   (I think)

secondlargest = 9 ( I think)

```
 if ((nums[i] > secondLargest) && (nums[i] < largestNum))
```

10 is not less then 10

The answer I get is correct, `secondLargest = 9;` I'm just not certain how the code arrived there.

Comment: That if clause doesn't execute when you run across the largest number, only when you run across a number between the second-largest and largest. I don't think it's executing on your last execution, it's likely running on some iteration before that.

Comment: why not do soething like ```return (nums.length > 2) ? nums.sort().reverse()[1] : nums[0] ```
this would sort the values and return the 2nd one...you should look into usort/other more efficient sort algorithms if you expect a large array

Comment: What's in the `nums` array?

Comment: If the case is `num[i] = 10` and `largestNum = 10`, then the update should not happen anyway. Hence the `&&` condition ensures that the duplicates are not considered as second largest number.

Comment: @staypuftman I just edited my question but it is an array of numbers of n length. So the input provided by HackerRank is n is given and random numbers fill the array

Comment: I'm going to be **that guy** - sort the array descending and return the second element. EDIT: I see @BrianPutt was already that guy, now I don't feel bad :)

Comment: @Adam what if there are duplicates?

Comment: @DaCat - touché. Going to have the get the first entry in the array that is smaller than the one at index 0 (after the descending sort). `const desc = nums.sort().reverse(); let i = 0; n = desc[i]; while(n >= desc[0]) {  i++; n = desc[i]; } return n;`

Comment: @Raymond - `console.log(Math.max(1, 2, 3, 5)-1)`

Comment: @Raymond I just went to that website and tried that, and added duplicates. Why does that method work with duplicates? Is it just built to disregard them?

Comment: @ElanHamburger Hm ok I think this is what I had trouble getting, thank you!

Comment: @DaCat I got confused with what you we're asking, give me a second.

Comment: @DaCat - his method doesn't work. It just subtracts 1 from the maximum in a set of numbers. `console.log(Math.max(1, 10, 100)-1)` obviously gives the wrong answer if you're looking for the second largest.

Comment: @BrianPutt doesn't sort put it in lexicographical order? If nums was 1,2,3...,10 wouldn't 10 be second largest? Also what if the max value has duplicates.

Comment: I don't think it's correct to initialize `secondHighest` to the same as `highest`.

Comment: @Adam ahh ok that makes sense. I see his method doesn't work, and I like the snippet you provided I can follow that logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use set to remove duplicates `data = [...new Set(data)];`, quick and easy.

```js
function secondHighest(data) {
 data = [...new Set(data)]; // Remove dupicates
        // New data after removing duplicates
 console.log('Data to test', data)
        // Max value placeholder
 let max = data[0];
        // Second largest placeholder
 let second_biggest = data[0];
        // For loop for our data length
 for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
               // If current item in data is > max
  if(data[i] > max){
                        // Second largest now equals max
   second_biggest = max;
                        // And max = current data item
   max = data[i];
  }
                // Else if data item > second largest and data item not equal to max
  else if (data[i] > second_biggest && data[i]!== max) {
   second_biggest = data[i];

  }
 }
 return second_biggest;
}

console.log(secondHighest([1, 2, 3, 4, 50, 60, 60, 7, 8, 9, 99]));
```

Comment: Nice job with Set to remove duplicates!

Comment: Thank you for explaining what `set` does. Your answer is very helpful, I find your else if statement easier to read then what I had. Thank you.

Comment: @DaCat No problem we could of done some fancy stuff, but since you were learning I figured if and simple else's would be better.

Answer (score 2):

With duplicates:

```js
const secondLargest = nums => {
  const desc = nums.sort((a, b) => a - b).reverse();
  let i = 0;
  let n = desc[i];
  while (n >= desc[0]) {
    i++;
    n = desc[i];
  }
  return n;
}

console.log(secondLargest([1, 77, 27, 54, 63, 77, 19, 72, 100, 200, 200, 79]));
```

EDIT:

Piggy-backing off another answer - just use `Set` and you can shorten it to:

```js
const secondLargest = nums => [...new Set(nums)].sort((a, b) => a - b).reverse()[1]
console.log(secondLargest([1, 77, 27, 54, 63, 77, 19, 72, 100, 200, 200, 79]));
```

EDIT #2:

Curious as to what the restrictions are on `nums` - is it possible for `nums` to be `[100,100]` for instance? Or what about `[100]`?

Comment: The constrains on the problem are 1<=n<=10 and 1<=nums<=100, ill update my question with this info, although I suspect the n value could be more than 10 and should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ES6, a nice solution is:

```
const nums = [7, 4, 9, 8, 4, 4, 2, 1, 9, 5, 2, 5, 3, 1, 7];
const numsUnique = [...new Set(nums)] // Remove duplicates
const sorted = numsUnique.sort((a, b) => a - b); // Order by ascending
const secondLargest = sorted[sorted.length - 2]; // Get the second last element
```

Comment: Slightly better to convert the array to a set before sorting.

Comment: You should probably sort after you do the Set, no?

Answer (score 0):

If I was you, I would make a max function to get the maximum number. Then I would filter out ever number that is not equal to the max, then run max again on the remaining array.

```js
function max(array){ // JavaScript already has Math.max, but it takes arguments so we apply
  return Math.max.apply(Math, array);
}
function secondMax(array){
  var a = array.slice(), m = max(array); // .slice() so original array is not affected
  a = a.filter(function(v){
    return v !== m;
  });
  return max(a);
}
console.log(secondMax([1, 77, 25, 72, 77, 23, 72, 21]));
```

Comment: How about: `[1, 77, 25, 77, 72]`?

Comment: Read the comments. Duplicates complicate things.

Comment: You can replace that `for` loop with `a = a.filter(e => e != m);`

Comment: Can you add explanation to the answer?

Comment: I follow that logic, just not the synatx used.